# How to print array contents in log file?

Tags: magento-1.7, log, array

How to print array contents into a log file in magento CE 1.7 without iterating through a loop?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
Mage::log(print_r($arr, 1), null, 'logfile.log');
```

Adding a second parameter to [print_r](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) will return a string with printed variable.
**[EDIT]**
based on the comments below I feel obligated to offer other options for logging an array.

```
Mage::log($arr, null, 'logfile.log');
```

or if you need a string prefix to the array

```
Mage::log('prefix'.Zend_Debug::dump($arr, null, false), null, 'logfile.log');
```

The second parameter of `Zend_Debug::dump()` is a label. If this is not `null` it will be added to before the array dump.
The third parameter of `Zend_Debug::dump()` means `echo`. If it's `true` then the dump result will be echoed, if it's `false` it will be returned as a string. In your case you need it to be `false`.

Comment: Thanks. It worked perfectly. I think you have missed the comma between the parameters of print_r function. Instead there was a full-stop.

Comment: @Su123 Yeah...I saw that . It's fixed now

Comment: You shouldn't need the `print_r` here, Magento's logger will autoexpand arrays and objects

Comment: If you insist on using `print_r`, a better choice might be to use `Zend_Debug::dump($var)`.

Comment: @Alan Storm : Thanks. I tested  your suggestion. It works perfectly.

Comment: Great way to debug. `var_dump` make crash magento in many cases. This is perfect to debug all `try-catch` sentences. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 11):

Have you tried to do just:

`Mage::log($array, null, 'logfile.log', true);`

Mage log method should expand the array it self.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. I don't know why it didn't work earlier when I check.

Answer (score 8):

As Petar pointed out, it is expanded, so if it is an array or an object, there is no print_r needed. But if you mix it, like:

```
Mage::log('my string' . $array);
```

you get a problem, because phps array to string conversion means:

```
array(... whatever...) -> 'String'
```

And with an object, php tries to call the __toString method if this doesn't exist, an error is thrown (I think).

And for reference, `Mage::log()`:

```
\Mage::log
/app/Mage.php:784
public static function log($message, $level = null, $file = '', $forceLog = false)
{
    // ...
    // initialize ... blah stuff...
    // check wether logging is on, developer mode or logging is forced

    try {
        // get the file, define the format... more stuff ... blah ...

        if (is_array($message) || is_object($message)) {
            $message = print_r($message, true);
        }

        $loggers[$file]->log($message, $level);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
    }
}
```

Nothing tested :-)

Comment: You are correct. I tested the code. If we put like Mage::log('my string' . $array); this will print 'my stringArray'