# Not valid template file error after zero dollar checkout

Tags: php, onestepcheckout

I got a new `Magento install with the rwd theme`. I offer my `visitors a 100% off coupon,` and when the price is zero dollars I get the option to pay with the `"No payment required"` option.

When I continue, `the order is set, customer and I receive our needed emails but the site shows an exception screen`. The exception is added below. `Somehow a template file is not found / invalid,` but I don't know which one.

**Can you guys point me in the right direction?**

```
a:5:{i:0;s:24:"Not valid template file:";i:1;s:4697:"#0 /myshop.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu_Renderer->_toHtml()
#1 /myshop.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#2 /myshop.nl/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml(34): Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu->getHtml('level-top')
#3 /myshop.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/cs068/dom...')
#4 /myshop.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#5 /myshop.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#6 /myshop.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#7 /myshop.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#8 /myshop.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#9 /myshop.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#10 /myshop.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('topMenu', true)
#11 /myshop.nl/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/header.phtml(46): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('topMenu')
#12 /myshop.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/cs068/dom...')
#13 /myshop.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#14 /myshop.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#15 /myshop.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#16 /myshop.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 /myshop.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('header', true)
#18 /myshop.nl/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/1column.phtml(42): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('header')
#19 /myshop.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/cs068/dom...')
#20 /myshop.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#21 /myshop.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#22 /myshop.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#23 /myshop.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#24 /myshop.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#25 /myshop.nl/app/code/local/Idev/OneStepCheckout/controllers/IndexController.php(75): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#26 /myshop.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Idev_OneStepCheckout_IndexController->indexAction()
#27 /myshop.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#28 /myshop.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#29 /myshop.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#30 /myshop.nl/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#31 /myshop.nl/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
#32 {main}";s:3:"url";s:17:"/onestepcheckout/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

EDIT: added `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml`

```
<?php
/**
 * Top menu for store
 *
 * @see Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu
 */
?>
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>
<?php if($_menu): ?>
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <?php echo $_menu ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

EDIT2: added `/app/design/frontend/rwd/NAME/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml` (Since I suspected an error in the topmenu). I tried placing the base file here and refreshed cache but to no help).

```
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>

<?php if ($_menu): ?>
    <nav id="nav">
        <ol class="nav-primary">
            <?php //--- home button hack ?>
            <?php $_anyActive = false;
            foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category) {
                $_anyActive = $_anyActive || $this->isCategoryActive($_category);
            } ?>
            <li class="level0 homelink"><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" class=level0><?php echo $this->__('Home') ?></a></li>
    <?php //--- /home button hack  ?>
    <?php echo $_menu ?>
        </ol>
    </nav>
    <?php
 endif ?>
```

EDIT 3. Added `/app/design/frontend/rwd/NAME/template/page/html/topmenu/renderer.php`

```
$html = '';

$children = $menuTree->getChildren();
$parentLevel = $menuTree->getLevel();
$childLevel = is_null($parentLevel) ? 0 : $parentLevel + 1;

$counter = 1;
$childrenCount = $children->count();

$parentPositionClass = $menuTree->getPositionClass();
$itemPositionClassPrefix = $parentPositionClass ? $parentPositionClass . '-' : 'nav-';

foreach ($children as $child) {
    $child->setLevel($childLevel);
    $child->setIsFirst($counter == 1);
    $child->setIsLast($counter == $childrenCount);
    $child->setPositionClass($itemPositionClassPrefix . $counter);

    $outermostClassCode = 'level' . $childLevel;
    $_hasChildren = ($child->hasChildren()) ? 'has-children' : '';

    $html .= '<li ' . $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) . '>';

    $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" class="' . $outermostClassCode . ' ' . $_hasChildren . '">' . $this->escapeHtml($this->__($child->getName())) . '</a>';

    if (!empty($childrenWrapClass)) {
        $html .= '<div class="' . $childrenWrapClass . '">';
    }

    $nextChildLevel = $childLevel + 1;

    if (!empty($_hasChildren)) {
        $html .= '<ul class="level' . $childLevel . '">';
        $html .= '<li class="level' . $nextChildLevel . '">';
        $html .= '<a class="level' . $nextChildLevel . '" href="' . $child->getUrl() . '">';
        // $html .=             $this->__('View All ') . $this->escapeHtml($this->__($child->getName()));
        $html .= '</a>';
        $html .= '</li>';
        $html .= $this->render($child, $childrenWrapClass);
        $html .= '</ul>';
    }

    if (!empty($childrenWrapClass)) {
        $html .= '</div>';
    }

    $html .= '</li>';

    $counter++;
}

return $html;
```

Comment: The template file is normally echoed in the exception. In your case it is "", a.k.a. empty. Which would mean your category navigation menu does not have a renderer set.

Comment: I noticed it is empty, as I went to the exception code and it stated: `throw new Exception('Not valid template file:' . $this->_templateFile);` . Could you please elaborate on the second part of your comment? How do I add a renderer set (And is that the question I should be asking :))?

Comment: may be app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml

Comment: @AmitBera I don't know how I can bend this file to my advantage, but I added the code. Thanks for your input!

Comment: as per  as log what /home/cs068/dom..? is it your magento instance location?

Comment: please check folder  and file permission your app/design/ folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Main issue has template file does not exits/emulated on your system.

According to your Log,a template file has been call from  `app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php` of  `toHtml()` function,which i`s not exits on system` that why  error has been thrown.

log say that template file does not exits  at

`/myshop.nl/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/`

or

`/myshop.nl/app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_TEMPLATE/template/`

### Debug:

**Print template file path on:** Please go to class `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu_Renderer`  at function `_toHtml()`and from here there error has coming.Check that the code:

```
        throw new Exception('Not valid template file:' . $this->_templateFile); was been set  error.
```

So you need `print the value of $this->_templateFile` name  and it `location` on `custom log file`.check how to create custom log file.  [How to print array contents in log file?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8675/how-to-print-array-contents-in-log-file)');

On The function:

```
$includeFilePath = realpath(Mage::getBaseDir('design') . DS . $this->getTemplateFile());

$this->getTemplateFile();
```

**Get template full path by:**

```
Mage::log(includeFilePath, null, 'logfile.log', true);
```

**Template  design location:**

```
Mage::log(Mage::getBaseDir('design'), null, 'logfile.log', true);
```

**And template path and name:**

```
Mage::log($this->getTemplateFile(), null, 'logfile.log', true);
```

Then on that log file `logfile.log`  you `can get  the missing file path and it details`.

**Check File location:**

After getting template path from log file,you need check the  template is exit on this folder  and in this case you need follow magento design  fallback system.Study  fallow About: [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magentos-theme-hierarchy),[Belvg](http://blog.belvg.com/magento-fallback-configuration-default-and-specific-themes-packages-design-exceptions-temporary-theme-configuration.html)

**Solutions:**  Then you need  to create template on this location.

**If exits the template then you need to check filer permission  and file type**.File type should be  phtml

**Solution:** Give proper permission to this template file for execute. the file

**Also,Magento system cannot render any php file from theme template folder**

So , need to remove `renderer.php`  from `app/design/frontend/rwd/NAME/template/page/html/topmenu/` and please put it on block class and then rendered the class.

As per as your code **NAME** (`app/design/frontend/rwd/NAME/template/page/html/topmenu/`) must `be your current rwd package template folder`

Comment: Amit! Thank you for your extensive answer! I was able to find the answer... By adding the three rules to the Log I noticed that `$this->getTemplateFile()` and `Mage::getBaseDir('design')` were not empty and the files were there, but $includeFilePath (you missed an $ in your answer) was empty. The `realpath()` function returned an empty string, and that was because the last bit of the url didnt have sufficient rights. As stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906513/realpath-returns-empty-string. Ill add the bounty as soon as it is eligible!

Answer (score 1):

The renderer is normally set in the `layout/page.xml` of the theme - when dealing with rwd. Since in this particular case you seem to fallback to `base/default`, where the renderer isn't specified, you seem to have a fallback issue. Does [this article](http://alanstorm.com/magento_parent_child_themes) shed light on your issue?

Comment: I learned a lot about fallbacks, but wasnt able to fix my problem using this info. Thanks though!