# Unable to Download downloadable products

Tags: product, error, downloadable

I was notified by one of my customer that he was unable to download the file that he bought recently. Whenever he clicks the link, website gives this error message-"An error occurred while getting the requested content. Please contact the store owner."

I tried checking this and found that he's true! I'm not able to figure out the exact reason for this.

Answer (score 2):

There may be multiple reason for this. First you need to find out whether Magento gives any errors (exception, errors, report) while you're trying to download the link. Go through - [**Fundamentals of Debug a Magento store**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/30183/3535) and come again with more details.

For now I can say that, you need to dig in the method `linkAction()` which is available in the controller class `Mage_Downloadable_DownloadController` that is located at `app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/controllers/DownloadController.php`. More specifically, this is the part of code that you need to dig into.

```
if ($status == Mage_Downloadable_Model_Link_Purchased_Item::LINK_STATUS_AVAILABLE
        && ($downloadsLeft || $linkPurchasedItem->getNumberOfDownloadsBought() == 0)
    ) {
        ...
        try {
            $this->_processDownload($resource, $resourceType);
            $linkPurchasedItem->setNumberOfDownloadsUsed($linkPurchasedItem->getNumberOfDownloadsUsed() + 1);

            if ($linkPurchasedItem->getNumberOfDownloadsBought() != 0 && !($downloadsLeft - 1)) {
                $linkPurchasedItem->setStatus(Mage_Downloadable_Model_Link_Purchased_Item::LINK_STATUS_EXPIRED);
            }
            $linkPurchasedItem->save();
            exit(0);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getCustomerSession()->addError(
                Mage::helper('downloadable')->__('An error occurred while getting the requested content. Please contact the store owner.')
            );
        }
    } elseif ($status == Mage_Downloadable_Model_Link_Purchased_Item::LINK_STATUS_EXPIRED) {
        $this->_getCustomerSession()->addNotice(Mage::helper('downloadable')->__('The link has expired.'));
    } elseif ($status == Mage_Downloadable_Model_Link_Purchased_Item::LINK_STATUS_PENDING
        || $status == Mage_Downloadable_Model_Link_Purchased_Item::LINK_STATUS_PAYMENT_REVIEW
    ) {
        $this->_getCustomerSession()->addNotice(Mage::helper('downloadable')->__('The link is not available.'));
    } else {
        $this->_getCustomerSession()->addError(
            Mage::helper('downloadable')->__('An error occurred while getting the requested content. Please contact the store owner.')
        );
    }
```

<sup>See the `catch` section and last `else` section</sup>

Try to log the error happens there. You can use `Mage::log()` function for that. **[Use this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8675/how-to-print-array-contents-in-log-file)** for more details on logging.

Comment: PLease is anything wrong with this code

Comment: Thanks! It is very useful to know a good place where to start your search!